# Looking for a function to determine if an org-mode entry has a tag

Tags: org-mode

I can use `(org-entry-get (point) "myproperty")` to get the value of the `myproperty` property for the current `org-mode` entry.

What about tags? Since a tag is either present or not, I was expecting some org API function such as `org-entry-has-tag` but there doesn't seem to be such a function. Am I missing something? If not, what's a good way to write such a function?

Comment: Do any of these help? org-get-buffer-tags, org-get-local-tags, org-get-local-tags-at, org-get-tag-face, org-get-tags, org-get-tags-at , org-get-tags-string, org-global-tags-completion-table, org-list-get-tag. If not, try `apropos`.

Comment: I used `apropos` and I don't have any of the "get tags" commands. I have a recent version of org, so I'm not sure why those aren't available.

Answer (score 4):

There is a [special property](https://orgmode.org/manual/Special-Properties.html#Special-Properties) called `TAGS`, so you can look up the tags of any entry the same way that you look up any other property:

```el
(org-entry-get (point) "TAGS")
```

And of course if there are no tags, that returns `nil`, so you can check for the existence of tags by using it in a conditional form, e.g. `(if (org-entry-get (point) "TAGS") ...)`.

Answer (score 1):

Somehow I didn't find `org-get-tags` -- I tried `apropos`, but it only showed me interactive functions, and `org-get-tags` isn't interactive. Thanks Drew.

For the exact question I have here, you just use `member` and `org-get-tags`:

```
(defun org-has-tag (tag)
  (member tag (org-get-tags)))
```

Comment: `C-h f org-*-tags TAB` will give you a completion buffer with all functions (not just interactive one) that match the pattern.

Comment: From `C-h f apropos`: "With `C-u` prefix, or if `apropos-do-all` is non-nil,
consider all symbols (if they match 1PATTERN1)." So try `C-u M-x apropos`.